# Free JqGrid: Sort DESC on first click

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm using Free JqGrid and I have an issue with sorting the columns. I use a remote data in my setup. I want the grid to load default without no sorting at all, but when the user clicks any of the sortable columns I want it to sort DESC first instead of ASC (which it will always do). I'd also like the (default) sorting icons to point in this direction.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use remote datatype (`datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"`) then the data will be displayed in the grid in the order in which it will be returned from the server. If your server sort the data based on the request from jqGrid then you need verify that you use no initial `sortname` parameter.

About your second problem. It's enough to add `firstsortorder: "desc"` property to the column definition to have DESC sort order on the first click of the user on the column header.